# get_pages Drop down list for selection of a page

Tags: plugin-development, dropdown

I am currently developing a plugin inside the admin page and I need to have a drop down list, listing all the pages. I need to be able to select one page and save the "ID" as an option. I am currently using this:

```
<select name="easyreg_redirect_page"> 
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php 
        $pages = get_pages(); 
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $option = '<option value="' . $page->ID . '">';
            $option .= $page->post_title;
            $option .= '</option>';
            echo $option;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

My 2 problems are:

1 - I would like the "Select Page" to always be available with an empty value
(and I will make a check that it cannot be selected but this is an other story ;-) )

2 - When I come back to my plugin Admin page I would like to see the page name that is currently saved in the options, neither and empty line nor the "Select Page".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You already have `<option value="">...</option>` you just need some extra attrs for it
2. You need to load current value and if value equals `$page->ID` than add attr `selected="selected"`

Here's how it could be done:

```
<select name="easyreg_redirect_page"> 
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php
        $selected_page = get_option( 'option_key' );
        $pages = get_pages(); 
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $option = '<option value="' . $page->ID . '" ';
            $option .= ( $page->ID == $selected_page ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            $option .= '>';
            $option .= $page->post_title;
            $option .= '</option>';
            echo $option;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

where's `option_key` you should enter options key where your value can be found ( where it saves it )

also, you could use wordpress `selected` function to write `selected="selected"`, then it would be like these:

```
$option = '<option value="' . $page-ID . '" ' . selected( $selected_page, $page->ID ) . '>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maikal... Exactly what I was looking for. I was just missing how to get the selected! I guess my programming is slowly getting there ;-) hehe Thanks a lot for your time!!